# Pointer Arithmetic? What is the difference between these three expressions?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

So I am trying to understand two things:

1. What are the differences between these three expressions?
2. What is the equivalent to the first expression (A)?

Here is the code (**fixed**):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void someFunc(double** pArray, int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        //this works perfectly
        double expressionA = *(*pArray + i);
        //this crashes : Unhandled exception at 0x00da13ff in pptrtest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
        double expressionB = **(pArray + i);
        //this crashes : Unhandled exception at 0x00da13ff in pptrtest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
        double expressionC = *pArray[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
    double arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    double* pArr = arr;

    someFunc(&pArr, sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be much better if you add code to show how you have allocated memory to the ppDoubleArray. That would give people answering your question a better insight as to what you are doing.

Comment: Did you mean `+ i`, not `+ 1`?

Comment: It also helps if you say what "this crashes" means. Does something explode? Is there an exception or error message? If you're not going to provide all your code, at least provide a **specific** error description. "this crashes" is meaningless most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is, that [] is applied before *, so in expr C you are doing

```
*(ppDoubleArray[i])
```

actually the equivalent of expr B, but the expr A does

```
(*ppDoubleArray)[i]
```

(assuming the 1 in the expression should be an i, otherwise thats different anyway).

Comment: Evaluation order and operator precedence are orthogonal.

Comment: Huh? Did I use wrong terminus, or is there another problem? I meant operator precedence.

Comment: @Christian: Yes, you did mean operator precedence. :) But you instead wrote "evaluation" in the answer.

Comment: The operator with a higher precedence gets evaluated first, doesn't it? What else do you mean with evaluation?

Comment: @Christian: Order of evaluation of expressions between sequence points is unspecified. I know what you're saying and you're essentially correct, but strictly speaking "evaluation" is not the right term to apply here.

Comment: Ok,I understand. Actually I once had such a problem, where the real compiled evaluation sequence didn't fit to what I came up in my simple mind with.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, The order of evaluation of *operands* is undefined. That does not come into play here. Operator precedence can definitely affect the order in which operators are evaluated. What Christian Rau said is actually correct.

Comment: @ikegami: That's exactly what I mean; evaluation does not come into play.

Comment: Operators are never evaluated, they are applied. (Operators don't even have values.) You should say "`[]` is applied before `*`".

Comment: I think after 50 comments on this and an "Ok, I understand" comment from me, you can assume, that I have realized I used the wrong term. But now you have gotten me that far, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @molbdnilo, "Operators are never evaluated, they are applied." may be true in C++'s jargon -- I have no idea either way -- but that's not true in general.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pointer to a pointer of double. Think of it as a pointer to an array of doubles. Either ways, the following is their meanings:

1. `double expressionA = *(*ppDoubleArray + 1);` is the same as: `double expressionA = *((*ppDoubleArray) + 1);`
2. `double expressionB = **(ppDoubleArray + 1);` is the same as: `double expressionB = *(*(ppDoubleArray + 1));` which means you want to de-reference `ppDoubleArray[1]` which am guessing doesn't exist.
3. `double expressionC = *ppDoubleArray[i];` is the same as: `double expressionC = *(ppDoubleArray[i]);` -- again, you are de-referencing `ppDoubleArray[i]` which does not exist.

Like everyone else said, you need to be mindful of the order of preference. Basically, dereference first then index your array.

Answer (score 1):

```
double expressionB = **(ppDoubleArray + 1);
```

Lets look at memory for this guy, on the stack you've got a pointer to a pointer to a double. So if its an address in memory for a 32-bit processor, the stack could look something like:

```
stack:  |ppDoubleArray ptr    |local vars, other args, or garbage |more locals/etc
addr:   |0 bytes from stack   |4 bytes from stack                 |8bytes...
```

So when we look at the first part of the expression

```
  (ppDoubleArray + 1)
```

This says "go one pointer past `ppDoubleArray`". Go to the next pointer by going to the next spot in memory. What is the next spot in memory past `ppDoubleArray`? Look at the stack above, its probably some local variables or the other argument. So now you have who knows what (maybe the contents of length? one of the doubles? garbage?) and you're going to treat it as if it were a valid address somewhere. You then follow that supposed pointer, by dereferencing:

```
   **(ppDoubleArray + 1)
```

And crash!

So, for example, if length was 5, ppDoubleArray+1 might grab 5 and dereference "5" looking for something at that address.

This code:

```
   double expressionC = *ppDoubleArray[i];
```

works the same way, the `[]` [take precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) over the dereference. So you go to the ith memory location past `ppDoubleArray` and assume its pointing at your array.

Rearranging the order of operations with parent would, however work:

```
   (*ppDoubleArray)[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ppDoubleArray is a pointer to an array of doubles:

The second one crashes because you are adding one to the pointer to the array not selecting the correct index from it.

The third one crashes because of the precedence of the operators. you are selecting the `i`th element which is not the array (unless i is 0) and then dereferencing that.

The important thing to remember here is how to deal with a pointer to an array (or a pointer to a pointer) You dereference it once to get to the array, at which point you can do the arithmetic and then dereference it again to get to the element.

Answer (score 0):

aSCII art Time:
`--->` = derefering

`double expressionA = *(*ppDoubleArray + 1);`

```
ppDoubleArray  ---> .  
                    +1  
                    . ---> expressionA
```

`double expressionB = **(ppDoubleArray + 1);`

```
ppDoubleArray
     +1
      . ---> . ---> expressionB
```

`double expressionC = *ppDoubleArray[i];`

```
ppDoubleArray
     +i
      . ---> . ---> expressionC
```